# one category of bars is smaller than rest and is not aligned with axis

Tags: r

Above dominance, the bars are smaller and don't align with the axis label.

```
x<- ggplot(avg, aes(x=avg$`NewData$treatment`, y=avg$sc, fill=as.factor(avg$`NewData$gender`)))+
  geom_bar(position= position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  ylab(lab="Effort")+
  xlab(lab="Treatment")+
  ggtitle("Effort Treatment and Gender")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Gender", breaks=c("1","2"), labels=c("Male","Female"))+
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("matrix_individual","matrix_tournament","matrix_fixed", "matrix_dictator"),
                 labels=c("matrix_individual" = "Piece-Rate", "matrix_tournament"= "Dominance", "matrix_fixed" = "Fixed", "matrix_dictator" = "Influence"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=10))
```

[image: image of barplot]

Comment: this means that dominance has 3 levels, whereas the others have 2. make sure only non-zero levels are included in the plot. hard to help you further without any data

Comment: Try taking out all the `avg$....` parts in the `aes` call - these are unnecessary, and do odd things to ggplot. Also if you can add some sample data (try a small part of your data set using `dput(avg, 20)`) that will help. You can also specify the bar width with `width = ` in your `geom_bar` call.

Comment: thank you! dominance did have 3 levels and i adjusted it :)